# perl grep matching variable from hash table

Tags: perl

I have the following code in perl that tries to find a string '$dataset' in the keys of %samples_runs and stores it in an array

```
} elsif ( my @matches = grep /$dataset/, keys %samples_runs ) { 
    my @values = @samples_runs{@matches};

    foreach my $match (@matches) {
    # do something
    }
```

However, if the 'keys %samples_runs' starts with "prefix-1-1", I don't want this to be considered as a match.

So when there is a match, this will evaluate to true 'grep /$dataset/, keys %samples_runs'. But when there is a match AND the keys%samples_runs starts with 'prefix-1-1', nothing should be added to the @matches array.

How can I implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by *'keys %samples_runs' starts with "prefix-1-1"*? Please show sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` will let you implement any conditions you like. So yes, it can be done.

```
my @matches = grep ( /$dataset/ and not /^prefix-1-1/, keys %sample_runs );
```

Should do what you want.

Comment: comman above was giving an error. Changed it to: elsif ( my @matches = grep /$dataset/ && ! /^prefix-1-1/, keys %samples_runs)